# Managing Roles with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, html, css

With, for example, somebody set as an **Admin**, there are some elements on the page which wouldn't usually be shown. Example: **Edit Group Name**

Of course, I can't just set this as `display: none;` for **Members**, as it is on a website, as this can be changed

How do I hide this completely for **Members** where it cannot be seen in DevTools?

Comment: 1) the HTML document that is sent by your backend (PHP, node/express, etc) is composed based on the role of the logged in user 2) a command like "edit group name" only works if the logged in user has sufficient privileges. However: since your question doesn't contain any mention of a backend I'm wondering if you aren't getting ahead of yourself?

Comment: What does this have to do with MongoDB?  Add a tag for it...

Comment: Looking at your previous question, you seem to know about PHP. Which specific DB system you use, (firebase, SQL, or mongoDB) doesn't really matter; that's just a convenient way of storing data on the server. What takes care of authentication and user roles is usually the backend, primarily by letting the user log in to establish a session. During the session, the user's role can be accessed at any time, so like I said, the backend commonly sends back HTML accordingly, i.e. links to administrative tasks don't appear in the first place unless the logged in user is an admin according to the DB.

Comment: But unless you're using a (PHP) framework with native support for user roles, you simply write the necessary code yourself.